# Add tags when creating product in Magento?

Tags: magento, tags

The "Product Tags" tab would only appear after a product has been created. Even then, there doesn't seem a way to add tags to a product - it only displays them when you are editing the product and I see only "Reset Filter" and "Search" buttons.

So the tags are only for customers? Not administrators?

Is there any way to add tags to products when creating them? Just like you can specify tags when you are creating blog posts in WordPress. It's an intuitive feature that helps classify the item (product or blog post) even better than categories and attributes (you can't use too many attributes or it won't be user friendly).

If this can't be done from control panel. Is there any way I can do this programmatically by Magento API?

Comment: I do this directly via SQL-Queries. Take a look at this tables: tag tag_properties tag_relation tag_summary Regards boti

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are THREE ways to do it:

A) to **add tags directly when entering/editing a product**, you will need an extension, such as [this one](http://icebergcommerce.com/software/magento-admin-product-tagging-extension.html). *This method is most useful to let people with less magento experience create tags (such as data entry people)*.

B) To **add tags without leaving the administrator** (not going to the frontend). *This is useful for applying the same tag to multiple products*:

> Create tags through Catalog->All Tags-> Add New Tag button.
>
> After creating the tags, click on each tag. You’ll see a detailed set
>   of options to “Edit Tag”.
>
> Go to the “Products tagged as administrator” tab, click on ‘Reset
>   Filter” . You see all your products getting listed.
>
> Select the products to which you want to assign the tag & click on
>   “Save Tag”.

C) To **add tags via the frontend & the backend**, which is *useful when you want to add a lot of tags to each single product*:

> Just create your products as normal. When you are ready to add tags to
>   your products just create yourself a customer account for your store
>   and go to each product and add them as a customer would. I wrote out
>   all of my tags in a text editor. Now since I am using phrases, and not
>   just words, my tags will be entered as:
>
> ‘Stylus C64’ ‘Stylus C66’ ‘Stylus C84’ ‘Stylus C84N’ ‘Stylus C84WN’
>   ‘Stylus C86’ ‘Stylus CX3600’ ‘Stylus CX3650’ ‘Stylus CX4600’ ‘Stylus
>   CX6400’ ‘Stylus CX6600’
>
> Take note that you need the single quote (’) to bracket your phrases…
>   or just spaces between each word if your tags are single words. Very
>   easy to write out and then copy/paste into the Add Your Tags section
>   of each product.
>
> Once you copy/paste your tags in the front-end you will be prompted
>   with a message that they must be approved from the admin/moderator.
>   Now log into the back-end and go to the tags section (Catalog > Tags >
>   Pending Tags). There you will see the list of tags you just submitted
>   from the front-end of the site. Now just click “Select All”, then from
>   the Actions drop-down menu choose “Change Status”, and then from the
>   status drop-down choose “Approved” and then “Submit”.

Now you can pick a method most appropriate for each type of use!

Comment: "Go to the “Products tagged as administrator” tab, click on ‘Reset Filter”" > thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: The link to the Plugin is broken. Add the missing l in html and it works.